# Подгрузка текста html

Tags: ajax, html, javascript

Здравствуйте, скажите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы текст в странице html подгружался не весь, а частями, например после того как довел до конца страницы погрузилось еще немного текста или при нажатии эдакой кнопки что-то похожее как в facebook сделан timeline который загружается не весь, а частями…

Comment: Ваш тег вопроса (*html*) обозначет, что вы ограничиваетесь только этим или такое, как JS, серверные языки вам так же не чужды? Если да, то вам потребуется, например, AJAX + PHP для подгрузки каких-либо данных из БД или, как минимум, JavaScript, с помощью которого, вы постепенно открываете статические блоки.

Comment: JS приветствуется, а вот AJAX + PHP к сожалению нет…

Comment: PHP не нужен, вернее не обязателен именно он. Достаточно просто AJAX и серверного приложения, которое может быть написано на чем угодно и в состоянии этот запрос обработать. Качаете jQuery ознакамливаетесь с простейшим руководством и пишите в свое удовольствие.

Comment: Вот вам [простой примерчик][1], а дальше всё зависит от вашей фантазии.

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/R3DLn/1/

Comment: Deonis
Получилось вставить ваш скрипт, именно то что нужно, но только как же добавлять разный текст, ведь добавляется одно и тоже, а мне нужно частями (разный) текст… (ну как пример возьмем рассказ как его реализовать через ваш шаблон, только чтобы он не добавлялся весь каждый раз нажимая еще, а частично последовательно добавлялся при нажатии первая глава, вторая глава и т.д.?)

Comment: @laizan, для этого, если брать в качестве примера рассказ, вам его надо изначально разбить на части и обернуть в блоки, которые в дальнейшем и расскрывать.

P.S. Вот [пример][1] ближе к реальности

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/R3DLn/3/